# Low graphics performance with Intel HD graphics

Tags: 11.04, graphics, performance, intel-graphics

hey, my laptop should be capable of running some games fine but doesn't. Examples are egoboo and tome. http://www.ebuyer.com/product/237739 this is my laptop.

I tried the gears test and i only get 60 FPS, on IRC they said thats a big issue and should try the forums. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and was told I should have the newest drivers.

```
neil@neil-K52F:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test --print
OpenGL vendor string:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile GEM 20100330 DEVELOPMENT 
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 7.10.2

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity supported:          yes
```

Comment: Open a terminal window and run `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test --print` and report below the output.

Answer (score 1):

You have 60 FPS because of VSync. Switch off in System settings -> Compiz settings -> OpenGL -> VSync

Comment: i dont have compiz listed there.

Comment: i got E: Unable to locate package ccsm

Comment: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`